Creality K1C printing holes as ovals not circles
I've had five Creality K1C CoreXY 3D printers for about four months. Recently, one of them started having issues where the printed holes aren't coming out as circles and the parts aren't accurate. I'm using the same G-code that works perfectly on my other K1C printers, where the holes print as they should. I've attached some pictures for comparison. I haven't found anyone with a similar issue yet, so any help is appreciated. If you think a calibration model would help diagnose the issue, feel free to suggest one and I'll print it. I'll send you pictures of the results.
What I have tried:

Tensioned the belt by following K1 Belt Tension ... How To Creality K1.
Greased the Z-axis lead screw.
Greased the X-axis rod.








The white one is also terribly underextruding... There are more problems than only oval holes! Have you seen 3d printer not printing circles correctly?

I will check the solution provided in that link and update you on how it works out.

after I tried calibrate the rotation distance and also tighten the belt the result is still the same, the only I haven't try is check for the slipping pulley. (I don't know how to fix a slipping pulley)

Your latest added calibration cube Z top layers photo still look awful. Seriously underextruding! But the developers of the cube did even worse than your printer does! See calibration cube on Thingiverse.

I tried cleaning the nozzle and also change the filament to a new one and result is still the same.

Good, now you know where to focus! The extruder.

do you have a guide or document for trouble shooting an extruder?
